# Want multiple match in if else statement

Tags: javascript

problem: I want to match muliple statement without breaking for just one.

**code:**

```
        if(options === "opt1"){
            obj['opt1Users'].push(userName);
            obj['opt1Count'] = resSurvey[0].opt1Count + 1;
        }
        else if(options  === "opt2"){
            obj['opt2Users'].push(userName);
            obj['opt2Count'] = resSurvey[0].opt2Count + 1;
        }
        else if(options === "opt3"){
            obj['opt3Users'].push(userName);
            obj['opt3Count'] = resSurvey[0].opt3Count + 1;
        }else if(options  === "opt4"){
            obj['opt4Users'].push(userName);
            obj['opt4Count'] =resSurvey[0].opt4Count + 1;
        }
```

Comment: Then use an `if` rather than `else if`. However in your case it doesn't make sense, as `options` can only be equal to one of the values

Comment: @GalAbra - That wouldn't make any positive difference to the above, as only one *can* match.

Comment: You can use Switch Statement.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - They can, but how would that improve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic property access via brackets notation, you could have a single `if` and create the property names with string concatenation:

```
if (options === "opt1" || options === "opt2" || options === "opt3" || options === "opt4") {
    obj[options + "Users"].push(userName);
    obj[options + "Count"] = resSurvey[0][options + "Count"] + 1;
}
```

*(If you already **know** that `options` will have one of those four values, you could do away with the `if` entirely.)*

That said, you might consider updating the structure of `obj` so you didn't need concatenation. For instance, if `obj` had properties for `opt1`, `opt2`, etc. that were objects, those objects could have `count` and `users` properties:

```
const entry = obj[options];
if (entry) { // Minor assumption here, that `options` matches our `opt1` etc. properties but not some *other* property of `obj`.
    entry.users.push(userName);
    entry.count = resSurvey[0][options + "Count"] + 1;
}
```

Comment: You are Right, But what if OP have any other naming convention rather then `opt2Users` etc ?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - We can only answer based on what's in the question. I'd assume the OP can handle changing the string concatenation as necessary to apply this to *other* code.